# What is the best way to implement a poller with timeout as a reactive stream.

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx-java2

What is the best way to model a poller with a timeout, where a certain condition causes an early-exit as 'reactive streams'?

e.g.

If I had an observable which produced a decreasing sequence of positive integers every second

```
9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
```

What is the best way to write a consumer which takes the latest single event after 5 seconds OR the '0' event if it produced earlier than the timeout.

This is my code as it stands at the moment: (Example in Java)

```
    int intialValue = 10;

    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(intialValue);
    Integer val = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .map(tick -> counter.decrementAndGet())
                            .takeUntil(it -> it == 0)
                            .takeUntil(Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                            .lastElement()
                            .blockingGet();

    System.out.println(val);
```

if initialValue = 10, I expect 6 to print. if initialValue = 2, i expect 0 to print before the 5 second timeout expires.

I'm interested if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: There are three elements in the observable chain: the source (`interval().map()`), the selection by value (`it == 0`), the selection by time (`timer()`). You won't get more compact than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is really a much better way than what you did. You have to have the following:

- An interval to emit on (`interval`)
- An aggregator to decrement and store the last value (`scan`)
- A termination condition on the value (`takeWhile`)
- A termination condition on time (`takeUntil(timer(...))`)
- Get the last value on completion (`last`)

Each one is represented by an operator. You can't do much to get around that. I used a few different operators (`scan` for aggregation and `takeWhile` for termination on value) but it is the same number of operators.

```js
const { interval, timer } = rxjs;
const { scan, takeWhile, takeUntil, last, tap } = rxjs.operators;

function poll(start) {
  console.log('start', start);
  interval(1000).pipe(
    scan((x) => x - 1, start),
    takeWhile((x) => x >= 0),
    takeUntil(timer(5000)),
    tap((x) => { console.log('tap', x); }),
    last()
  ).subscribe(
    (x) => { console.log('next', x); },
    (e) => { console.log('error', e); },
    () => { console.log('complete'); }
  );
}

poll(10);
setTimeout(() => { poll(2); }, 6000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.1.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not clear on how you expect it to function on the boundaries. In your example you always decrement before emiting so if your initial value is 10 then you emit 9, 8, 7, 6 (4 values). If you wanted to start with 10 then . you could do `scan(..., start + 1)` but that would end you at 7 because the timer in the `takeUntil(...)` aligns with the source interval so that 6 would be excluded. If you want to emit 5 values then you could do `takeUntil(timer(5001))`. Also, if you don't want to wait a second to emit the first value then you could put `startWith(start)` right after the `scan(...)`. Or you could do `timer(0, 1000)` with `scan(..., start + 1)` instead of the source interval.

Also note that the termination on value (`takeWhile`) will not terminate till the invalid value is produced (`-1`). So it will continue for a second after receiving the termination value (`0`). It seems that most of the termination operators work that way where if they terminate on some value then they wont let the others through.

You could do a `take(5)` instead of `takeUntil(timer(5000))` because you know it fires on a matching interval if that works for your scenario. That would also get around the issue of excluding the last value because of the timers lining up.